# Neo4j order result with case insensitively

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have following data

'user' node- with 'name' property having following values

```
 abc
 xyz
 XYZ
 ABC
```

I need result like this, When i order it by ascending order.

```
 abc
 ABC     
 xyz     
 XYZ
```

my query is

```
MATCH (u:user) 
return u 
order by u.name ASC;
```

But The result is

```
abc
xyz
ABC
XYZ
```

How can we do case insensitive ordering in neo4j ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can achieve what you are after in straight Cypher, depending on exactly what you want to achieve you can utilise a String function (this will make ABZ and abz equal though) to effectively remove case from the ordered field..

```
MATCH (u:user) 
RETURN u 
ORDER BY LOWER(u.name) ASC;
```